# Python pika library sporadic behavior, dropping messages

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am using pika in a production system and have noticed both BlockingConnection and SelectConnection have been dropping a message here and there with no apparent errors or warnings. Unfortunately, I am not able to post code, but wanted to solicit any guidance or anecdotes from other users who may have experienced this kind of behavior. I have heard that RabbitMQ is extremely solid, so I am beginning to question the reliability of pika and wonder whether there are more trusted alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem you might be seeing has to do with the way `basic.publish` is defined.  It always succeeds.  There will not be any traffic expected from the server in case of error (or success, for that matter).

The portable way to resolve this is to wrap the publish in a transaction:

```
channel.tx_select()
channel.basic_publish(exchange='foo', ...)
channel.tx_commit()
```

The `tx_commit()` call will force the server to respond with an tx.commitok once it has successfully handled all of the actions it has received.  Your application should wait until the `tx.commit` succeeds; then you can be sure that all the messages sent were successful.

Slightly less portable is the rabbitmq specific extension `channel.select`, which causes the server to respond with a `basic.ack`.  I'm afraid I have never got that feature to work with pika's `BlockingConnection`, though, but you might have better success.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your insight, thanks! However, now that I have wrapped the call as you suggest, I get this error: ERROR - base_connection.py : _handle_error - SelectConnection: Socket is closed....though the application is able to continue. Is there some auto reconnect I am not seeing?

Comment: 'able to continue?' what does that mean, exactly,  the default NullReconnectingStrategy does nothing on connection close (you'll just be 'down')  You might want to provide a different strategy, or add some additional callbacks with `Connection.add_on_close_callback()`

Comment: So, after further analysis, I have managed to boil down the error...I think. What is happening is that we have two producers writing to the same exchange and storing messages in the same queue. There is one consumer placing these messages into a DB - so effectively a 2-feeding-1 type messaging setup. If I send 200 messages, 100 each, one of the two is ALWAYS able to send all of its messages, while the other is somehow cut-off. So, I see things like 100 and 12, or 100 and 61, but one is always able to completely succeed, while the other is not. Thoughts? I greatly appreciate your time on this.

Comment: Without seeing some actual code, it's probably not going to be possible to see what might be going wrong.